# How to change Google Forms date format to MM/YY?

Tags: google-forms

Is there any way to change the Drive Forms date format in the survey question to `MM/YY`? It currently only seems to allow `dd/mm/yy`?

I'm not interested in the day and it will confuse my respondents.

Comment: Hi Jacob, just saw your profile, you are a guru! Can I assume that the lack of answers to my Q means that it can't be done? Thanks, Barb

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to split the question into two separate parts:

- What month (validation = integer between 1 and 12)
- What year (validation:  integer greater than whatever you choose).

Then use a helper column to the right of the results in the underlying spreadsheet to calculate the date value you want, with a formula like

> =date(year(A2),month(A2),1)

There's an example of the date calculation here:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIeA4zAjID0y1jo1FnsbfGA4qmpRgAxMykLXi1pOfhc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I, too was frustrated with not being able to omit the day.  So I re-worded the question to "Enter the month/year of the equipment return.  Enter answer as MM/YYY" and had it be a short answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible through Google Forms.

In the web view, you only have the option of removing the year - day and month are still required. I dug into the API documentation to see if a custom form could be created with a script. But, even in the scripting process, the only variable you can drop is `includesYear()`. A similar class for month or day is not available.

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-item) for the `dateItem` class in Google Forms for more information.